# Dax Rolling Average with multiple records per day

Tags: statistics, powerbi, dax

Take a simple table

```
SalesTime
Product
UnitsSold
```

There is one row per sale. So there are multiple rows per day. I need a chart that will show the average units sold per sale over 7 days and average units sold per day over 7 days.

The examples that I found all used `DATESBETWEEN` or `DATESINPERIOD` and those throw an error if the table has multiple records per date.

Comment: Are you looking to write a calculated column that has these averages or do you want write a measure to drop into a visual?

Comment: I was assuming a Measure to drop into a visual or matrix/pivot. I didn't know that PowerBI columns could have aggregate calculations like this that spanned rows.

Answer (score 0):

I will name this table `Sales` and assume that `Sales[SalesTime]` is a date type rather than a datetime type. If not, create a new calculated column

```
Sales[SalesDate] = Sales[SalesTime].[Date]
```

and work with that instead.

Your rolling average units per sale can be calculated something like this:

```
AvgUnitsPerSale = 
VAR CurrDay = MIN(Sales[SalesTime])
RETURN CALCULATE(
            AVERAGE(Sales[UnitsSold]),
            DATESBETWEEN(Sales[SalesTime], CurrDay-7, CurrDay))
```

You can get an average count of sales per day by using `COUNT` instead of `AVERAGE`. To get the average units sold per day, multiply the average count of sales and the average units per sale.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient.
This is not working. I assume you meant Sales[SalesDate] in your code. It still didn't work. First it gave 'An invalid numeric representation of a date value was encountered' error (this is strange because the data is coming from SQL Server where the column is `DateTime Not Null`. When I changed `MIN(Sales[SalesDate])` to `MIN(Sales[SalesDate].[Date])` there are no errors. Yet the data is still a straight daily average. The only difference is that it no longer responds to slicers

Comment: `Sales[SalesDate]` was created as you instructed as column with the code `Sales[SalesDate] = Sales[SalesTime].[Date]` (where `[SalesTime]` came straight from the non nullable SQL table.) and formatted as a `Date` data type in the 'Modeling' ribbon

Comment: @Rabbi Hmm. Any chance you can share a stripped down .pbix file scrubbed of any sensitive data or some sort of minimal working example of what you're seeing? This sort of thing can be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I will try to do that, but it may be a few days before I have time for a project like that.